# Использование UserControl в ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

подскажите пожалуйста, ради эксперимента в качестве Item ListBox использую вместо шаблона UserControl который связан в словаре ресурсов с моделью представления следующим образом:

```
<datatemplate datatype="{x:Type vm:QuestionModelView}">
    <vw:questitonview/>
</datatemplate>
```

в итоге ListBoxItem отображается в соответствии с разметкой QuestitonView (это мой UserControl) за исключением того, что привязанные к QuestionModelView данные НЕ ОТОБРАЖАЕТ.
Вот разметка элемента управления

```
<grid datacontext="{Binding}" width="auto">
    <stackpanel>
        <textblock grid.row="0" height="20" fontsize="16"
                   text="{Binding path=Name}" horizontalalignment="Center"/>
        <textblock grid.row="1" fontsize="16"
                   text="{Binding Path=QuestionField}"
                   horizontalalignment="Center" width="auto"/>
    </stackpanel>
</grid>
```

Вот сам ListBox

```
<listbox grid.column="1" x:name="listy" 
         itemssource="{Binding QuestionsVms}"
         itemcontainerstyle="{StaticResource BoxThemeItemStyle}" 
         issynchronizedwithcurrentitem="True" minwidth="500" width="auto"  
         minheight="200" height="auto" margin="0,5">
</listbox>
```

Вот код модели представления

```
    public class QuestionModelView : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
    {
    public AllQuestionModelView _parent;
    public Question Model { get; private set; }
    #region Свойства
    public  string Name {get{ return Model.Name; }set { Model.Name =  
    value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name)); } }

    public string QuestionField { get { return Model.QuastionField; } set  
    { Model.QuastionField = value;  
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(QuestionField)); } }
    public ObservableCollection<AnswerModelView> AnswerModelViews { get;  
    set; }
    #endregion // Свойства
    #region Конструктор
    public QuestionModelView(Question q,AllQuestionModelView parent)
    {
        AnswerModelViews = new ObservableCollection<AnswerModelView> 
    (q.Answers.Select(a=>new AnswerModelView(a,this)));
        AnswerModelViews.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
       _parent = parent; Model = q;
        PropertyChanged += OnVerifingProperty;
    }
    #endregion //Конструктор
    #region Обработчики коллекций
    void OnCollectionChanged(object sender,  
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
            foreach (AnswerModelView AnswerVM in e.NewItems)
            {
                AnswerVM.PropertyChanged += this.OnAnswerPropertyChanged;
     }
        foreach (AnswerModelView AnswerVM in e.OldItems)
        {
            AnswerVM.PropertyChanged -= this.OnAnswerPropertyChanged;


        }

    }

    private void OnAnswerPropertyChanged(object sender,
    PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    #endregion //Обработчики коллекций

    private void OnVerifingProperty(object sender,  
    PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return null; } }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return this.GetValidationError(propertyName); }
    }
    string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(ValidatedProperties, propertyName) < 0)
            return null;

        string error = null;

        switch (propertyName)
        {
            //case nameof(Name):
            //    error = this.ValidateName(); break;
            //case "Num": error = this.ValidateNameOfNum(); break;
        }
        return error;
    }

    static readonly string[] ValidatedProperties =
    {

       //

    };

    }
```

Comment: А если `datacontext="{Binding}"` убрать? Покажите что такое `QuestionsVms`, коллекция `QuestionModelView`? Покажите класс `QuestionModelView`

Comment: Да datacontext необходимо убрать, QuestionsVms это коллекция QuestionModelView. вот код этой модели представления

Comment: Добавил QuestionModelView в основной свой вопрос, на другом форуме сказали чтобы отображались свойства этой модели в UserCotrol`е необходимо в последнем реализовать свойства зависимости для отображения свойств модели представления, каково Ваше мнение!

Comment: Кстати после того как убрал datacontext ничего не изменилось

Comment: Причем в других случаях, когда UserControl не используются в качестве listboxitem, а используются в качестве шаблонов например ContentTemplate какого нибудь контейнера, свойства зависимости не требуются, правда я еще не проверял совет со свойствами зависимости на практике.

Comment: А `BoxThemeItemStyle` что такое? Он случаем DataContext нигде не меняет?

Comment: *чтобы отображались свойства этой модели в UserCotrol`е необходимо в последнем реализовать свойства зависимости для отображения свойств модели представления* - бред

Comment: BoxThemeItemStyle ничего не меняет, он стиль задает и не связан с привязкой данных. То что вы называете бредом работает, а то что  пишите Вы так это в основном безнадежные попытки разобраться в вопросе, на который на другом форуме я сразу же получил хоть какой-то ответ. Мне скинули вариант ответа в качестве решения, там реализовано два текстовых свойства зависимости, через них отображаются свойства модели, а потом все это реализуюется через ListBoxItem. Что здесь бредового, не знаю, вроде это WPF по всем канонам. Вы наверное в своем каком-то мире живете, удачи!

Comment: Ну я мог бы вам показать, что никакие свойства зависимости дополнительные не нужны, но это не является сутью вопроса, поэтому здесь не место. Проблема вашего вопроса в том, что в нем по сути отсутствует *минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример*, без него что-то додумывать и сочинять самостоятельно неохота.

Comment: *BoxThemeItemStyle ничего не меняет, он стиль задает и не связан с привязкой данных* – ну как бы в стиле тоже запросто привязки можно сделать и часто там они есть, так что возмущение не по делу

Comment: Я не возмущаюсь, привязку данных я делаю в стиле если заключаю в него шаблон данных, в него же эту привязку и включаю, но здесь другой случай. Шаблон данных ассоциируется с моделью представления (QuestionModelView) через ресурс, на фига делать в каком то стиле еще одну привязку. По поводу самодостаточного примера я так понимаю решение скинуть? я весь код который имеет непосредственное отношение скинул. Пример теперь уже точно вполне самодостаточный. На все наводящие вопросы ответил. И не возмущаюсь. Извините если задел чем-то.

Comment: Особенность в том что этот контрол используется в качестве листбокситем. Я знаю что должно было работать и так. Но не работает. Убирал все о чем вы говорили, чтобы исключить вмешательство в датаконтекст. Но работает только со свойствами зависимости.